# Is there any way to run django south schema-migration programmatically?

Tags: django, django-models, migration, django-south

can anybody suggest me a way to programmatically run

```
/manage.py schemamigration appname --auto
```

I am creating models dynamically and i want to fake this migration at the time of model creation so that it wont raise an error when i want to change my model next time.

Comment: It's an interesting topic, here's a link I found useful: https://dynamic-models.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pdfindex.html#schema-and-data-migrations-with-south. Actually the whole thing this link points to is talking about creating models dynamically.

Comment: @ShangWang Thanks for the link, but the problem is there is no migration file created during dynamic model creation and it cause an error on next manual schemamigration.